# HTTP Components encoding problem

Tags: java, character-encoding, apache-httpcomponents

When using HTTP Components (java library for http) the response I get has `'` displayed as `Æ` and `-` displayed as `ȗ`.

Comment: Can you check the `Content-Encoding` response header and paste the value here?

Comment: The content encoding is null. Am I supposed to set it when I make my request?

Comment: Oh, are you in control of __both__ the server __and__ the client?

Comment: Just the client. But I have the exact same code in C# and I don't have this problem.

Comment: Let's handle this as an answer since writing in this tiny boxes makes me uneasy. If I don't help you I can always delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so basically you are getting a response without `Content-Type` from a server you are not in control of, and you're having encoding issues.

In `java` every string is internally handled as **Unicode strings**, despite the format they come in.

So I'm guessing your problem is where you are displaying this characters, either to the console or to a file.

The console will use the default charset to print the chars there. In my machine for example is `MacRoman`, not `utf-8`.

So what you need is to get the raw bytes from the response and do something like this:

```
System.out.println(new String(raw_byte_array, "utf-8"));
```

Also, this might shed some light in the matter:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html

Comment: I am just displaying this to a console.

Comment: `Content-Encoding` is data compression.  You mean `charset`.

Comment: @dan04, Indeed. @Reflux can you check the `Content-Type` property for the `charset` attribute?

Comment: Well I know the character set is UTF-8 but I specified that when I converted the value to a string.
    `EntityUtils.toString(response, "utf-8");`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the content is UTF-8? Note that from the javadocs on EntityUtils, the charset you pass as a parameter is used __if no charset is found in the HttpEntity___

Comment: I mean that's what is in the charset in the http headers.

Comment: Ok the issue seems to be in the actual traffic and java was decoding it as `utf-8`.  `0xc386` is `Æ` in `utf-8`.  Also in C# if you output the text in a `FileStream` or look at the console the `Æ` is there. However if you redirect the output to a text file then the correct character `'` is displayed. But it doesn't work in Java.
Weird.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version 4.x, you would use something like below to be Charset agnostic -

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
Charset charset = ContentType.getOrDefault(entity).getCharset();
```